# The time-reversibility of the semi-implicit Euler numerical integration method

Tags: math, simulation, game-physics, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

It's clear that the [semi-implicit Euler integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method) method is symplectic, but I can't find any info about it's **[time-reversibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing)**. So the question: is it time-reversible?

Comment: yes it's symplectic. the question is about it's time-reversibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Hooke's law example in [Semi-implicit_Euler_method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method)

```
v_{n+1} = v_n - omega^2 x_n dt
x_{n+1} = x_n + v_{n+1} dt
```

One way of thinking about reversibility is whether we can recover `v_n` and `x_n` given `v_{n+1}` and `x_{n+1}`. Rearranging the second

```
x_n = x_{n+1) - v_{n+1} dt
```

so we can find `x_n`, knowing this we can find `v_n`

```
v_n = v_{n+1} + omega^2 x_n dt
```

Note this is different from what you would get it you ran the  semi-implicit Euler method backwards by reversing the time with `dt = - dt`. Doing that you would do the two steps in the other order.

```
v_n = v_{n+1} + omega^2 x_{n+1} dt
x_n = x_{n+1} - v_n dt
```

In this [Google spreadsheet with Hooke's law](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19_a4CorZ5iVaNno1SNxKPqTRn2bvVVNuJBtnOuUaeU4/edit?usp=sharing) I've implemented the method for Hooke's law. Columns B and C are the position and velocity going forward. Columns D and E are starting at the end and applying the method with reversed time. Columns F and G start from the end but apply the method which recover the original data. You can see the graphs going forward and backwards don't quite match.

Comment: Practically yes. The definition of time reversibility in the wikipedia article is a little bit complex so I'm not sure of the theoretical answer.

Comment: Yes this is very confusing. I can't really decide what does the time-reversibility of an integrator mean. For example the Verlet methods are theoretically time-reversible. I created a related question on mathoverflow too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448005/what-does-time-reversibility-of-some-symplectic-integrators-mean.